# E/HmsSiteKit_TextSearchTaskApiCall_270: responseErrorCode errorCode = 10001

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

**Getting the above error in the HMS site kit**

com.android.huawei.sitekit E/SearchPlaceFragment: onSearchError is: 10001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with AGC or API key issue ,check API key in App Gallery console.